# is it possible to update tcp window scaling factor after 3-way handshake by sending a syn/ack?

Tags: networking, tcp

tcp window scaling factor is notified during 3-way handshake period
is it possible to update tcp window scaling factor after 3-way handshake

for example, by sending a SYN/ACK with tcp header option including a new tcp window scaling factor?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe paragraph 2.1 of [RFC1323](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1323.txt) addresses your question.